# Unable to Download macOS Mojave from App Store, error prompted: "Update not found, the requested version of MacOS is not available"

Tags: macos, mojave, catalina, mac-appstore, bootable-disk

I'm running Catalina on a MB Pro 2019 and I'm trying to create a separate volume running Mojave through a bootable external device. I've been doing this earlier this year and I had no problem whatsoever doing it, but as of today, when I try to download Mojave from the App Store, as soon as I press the "Get" button, Software Updates prompts and I get this error: "Update not found, the requested version of MacOS is not available", and I can't download it. I've been using the App Store link found at step four of this link:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210190

The result is I'm unable to download this version of MacOS and therefore I cannot proceed in the creation of a bootable device. Any advices on how to solve this problem? Does Apple also provides a direct link to download this OS?